# Proof that $8\cos^4(\phi)=\cos(4\phi)+4\cos(2\phi)+3$

Tags: trigonometry

Hi fellow mathematicians,
I want to proof that

$8\cos^4(\phi)=\cos(4\phi)+4\cos(2\phi)+3$

but somehow I cant figure out how to do that.
Do you know an elegant proof?

Help appreciated!

Comment: Use the double angle formula: $\cos 2 \phi = 2\cos^2 \phi - 1$.

Comment: Why was this edited...?

Comment: Your edits of your questions are obliterating their contents. Don't do that.

Comment: @Blue There is another offending post for someone with more permissions than I to fix... even worse, the answer bounties and accepted years ago is nonsense too

Comment: @FShrike: I've rolled-back a few questions. This rampant self-vandalism should be brought to the attention of moderators. (Am I imagining that the username has changed a couple of times in the past few minutes? There may be more going on.)

Comment: @Blue The username is indeed changing. This is another case of a user feeling embarrassed about their past questions I think; I’ve seen something similar before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Euler's formulas:
$$
\cos\alpha=\frac{e^{i\alpha}+e^{-i\alpha}}{2}
$$
so you get
$$
2(\cos4\phi+4\cos2\phi+3)=
e^{4i\phi}+4e^{2i\phi}+6+4e^{-2i\phi}+e^{-4i\phi}=
(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi})^4=16\cos^4\phi
$$